# SSP indexing /Pages/ and causing Access Denied search results

Tags: 2007, search, permissions

We have an SSP indexing our site using a read-only account to spider the content.

We have an issue that the SSP is indexing /pages/ without the name of an aspx. When returning search results this causes an Access Denied error when clicking on the link for anonymous users, although /pages/default.aspx does not require login.

Why does /pages/ not redirect to /pages/default.aspx for anonymous users like it does for authenticated users? The entire site is setup to allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem. The url's in the Search results end with /Pages/ .
they should redirect to /Pages/default.aspx but anonymous users where asked to log in if they want to follow the link.

Our solution:
We found out that the subsites didn't inherite the permissions from it's parent site anymore (initially they did). After changing that our search result problem was fixed.
Finally we manually started a crawl.